# Change orientation on tapping Imageview iPhone

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, screen-orientation

I am a new iOs developer. I have created an iPhone application where i have used a UIImage view. I have set a example.png on the imageview . When user tap on Image then I want to Change the screen orientation in Landscape mode and set full screen image on the landscape screen . How can i do this.Please help me . Thanks in advanch.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to define Frame for ImageView. Then get the Touch event of Imageview.

Now if User touches the ImageView then Set the Frame of UIView in LandScape Mode, OtherWise in Portrait Mode.